# jmeter: pick user from csv file only once

Tags: jmeter

Does jmeter support functionality of picking a userid from csv just once?

If not, Has anyone tried option of saving the user id in a jmeter property and then. before using the next random user, check if a property with that value already exists?

Details: We have 200 user ids in CSV file. Script picks up a random one and logs in as that user and performs one time initialization tasks, that are not performed during subsequent logins. So we want to avoid the same user ID picked up again from csv file and make sure that all 200 user ids are eventually initialized.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain a little bit what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far.

Comment: @Adnan Updated description

Comment: Single user uniqueness or multi user uniqueness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid user ID picked up again from CSV File, then just use regular [CSV Dataset](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Just set :

- Recycle on EOF to false
- Stop thread on EOF to true

Comment: Each user will randomly pick an item right ? CSV can be shuffled

Comment: As he said... But if you shuffle csv, there is huge chance users will pick same cell.

Comment: Not if you have 200 Threads and with the config I provided, each thread will pick a line and when no more data available , thread will end

Comment: It works if you shuffle csv before actual use, but if you wanna have dynamic random picking it will not work. Your idea is good for the first case!

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK This is a good solution for us since we don't need randomness in this case. but we do want multiple threads to pick up user ids at the same time. Will it happen in a mutually exclusive way in some synchronized manner among multiple threads?